# Make a systemd service that changes /dev/null modification time

Tags: systemd, autostart

I have my files sorted by date to easily work with the most recent files. I also have a bunch of logs redirected to `/dev/null` in my home directory that I would like to be shown at the end. I tried to create a systemd service for this, but it doesn't work somehow:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/devnull1975.service 
[Unit]
Description=Change /dev/null modification time to 1975
After=display-manager.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/touch -c -t 197501010000 /dev/null

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

It works if I start it manually and it is being run on reboot. "after display manager" looks like a point where `/dev/null` was already created but after reboot it still has current date is `stat` output. So, can anyone see what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, /dev/null is a special file, not a directory. It's primary purpose is to handle redirection of stdout and stderr. When logs are redirected to the folder, they no longer exist.

Some reference material, [Here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

With regards to the files in your home directory, it may better to switch from the direct command: `/usr/bin/touch -c -t 197501010000 /dev/null`

To

```
/usr/local/bin/mynewscript.sh
```

Though use your own new file name. So with your favorite editor create the new file, add contents such as: (Change the names accordingly)

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/touch -m -t 197501010000 /home/username/.bzr.log
/usr/bin/touch -m -t 197501010000 /home/username/.xsessions-errors.old
/usr/bin/touch -m -t 197501010000 /home/username/.php_history
/usr/bin/touch -m -t 197501010000 /home/username/.recently-used
```

Set execute, on your file:

```
chmod 455 /usr/local/mynewscript.sh
```

Next change your service file: /etc/systemd/system/devnull1975.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Changes modified times on log file locate /home/username/
After=graphical-session.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh /usr/local/bin/mynewscript.sh
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=file-touch.service
```

Use the following to verify no errors are found with the .service file

```
systemd-analyze verify /etc/systemd/system/devnull1975.service
```

Refer to this [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#Example_Services) for more information on systemd.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I'll try to explain it with picture: http://i.imgur.com/75LZ7mF.png I tried to do it in a separate executable file and with `multi-user.target` as you suggested and it still didn't autostart. Also I had to remove the `Alias` line, otherwise it wasn't possible to enable it.

Comment: @int_ua: Thank you for providing the extra details. What kept it from running, was the ExecStart, full paths must be include, and when calling scripts, must also include the executable that will be launching them. The alias failed, least in my case, because I had a file in /etc/systemd/system with the same name as the alias.

Comment: It is running, actually. The problem is that it somehow runs before the last thing that changes `/dev/null`: for example with current state, copied from this answer it was run on `17:43:58` and `/dev/null` shows modification time `17:44:04`. AFAIU, we just need to find the `systemd` service that modifies it and write it to `After` of our service.

Comment: ... or just add a `sleep` command before touching! Trying that. Of course, the ideal solution would still be to find the relevant service

Comment: In /etc/systemd/system there is likely, a service by the name of display-manager.service. Try changing the line starting with after to look like After=display-manager.service

Comment: Tried that before, didn't work unfortunately. For now I've added `sleep`ing for several seconds and it's working